# get todays entries from db is always zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get todays entries from my db data ,
how ever I keep getting 0(zero ) results ,
this is the code I have tried

```
var ddt = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
        ViewBag.rrr = ddt;//Ok result-09-Oct-16 23:59:59: 
        var upCommingLecture = _context.LectureGigs
        .Include(g => g.Artist).Include(g => g.Genre)
        .Where(g => (g.DateTime == ddt));//Results zero in my db i have 1 item on todays date
```

Comment: Your ddt contains also the time part, are you sure that your g.DateTime contains exactly the same time part? What happens if _.Where(g => (g.DateTime.Date == ddt.Date)_

Comment: Do you really have a record that has exactly that date and time (to the nearest millisecond)? I assume you want to compare the date component only

Comment: @Steve I have tried this > var ddt = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1).Date;  but 0 results.

Comment: @Stephen I would like anything on today under 23:59:00 , sorry I wasn not clear

Comment: `DateTime minDate = DateTime.Today; DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Today.AdDays(1);` then `.Where(g => g.DateTime >= minDate && g.DateTime < maxDate)`

Comment: If you want something under 23:59:00 then why do you ask for an exact match?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks ,works great!

Comment: g.DateTime.Date == ddt.Date